# "Full screen" <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe

When I use the following code to create an iframe:

```
<iframe src="mypage.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%">Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
```

The iframe doesn't go all the way—a 10px white "border" surrounds the iframe. How could I solve this?

Here is an image of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of site]

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The `body` has a default margin in most browsers. Try:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

in the page with the `iframe`.

Answer (score 458):

To cover the entire viewport, you can use:

```
<iframe src="mypage.html" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
```

<strike>And be sure to set the framed page's margins to 0, e.g., `body { margin: 0; }`.</strike> - Actually, this is not necessary with this solution.

I am using this successfully, with an additional `display:none` and JS to show it when the user clicks the appropriate control.

Note: To fill the parent's view area instead of the entire viewport, change `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` and make sure the parent has a position other than `static`.

Comment: This answer solves how to make iframe occupy the whole screen

Comment: You can also use [viewport-percentage lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27832759/2680216)..

Comment: Works perfectly with HTML 5

Comment: Is there a way to do this without position relative?

Comment: @dwbartz: Do you mean "without position fixed"?

Comment: @dwbartz: Fixed is what makes it relative to the viewport. What are you be wanting to achieve?

Comment: Checked with Apple emulator. Safari isn't compatible.

Comment: @ChrisvanChip is it still not compatible with current versions of safari ?

Comment: @beppe9000 Unsure, I'd recommend you to check it using compatibility documentations.

Comment: Thanks exactly what i needed to fix that gap at the bottom of my iframe

Comment: The above answer has a scrolling bar.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10619459/5033247

Answer (score 53):

You can also use [viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) to achieve this:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

Where `100vh` represents the height of the viewport, and likewise `100vw` represents the width.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qegaezk6/)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
}
iframe {
    display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
    background: #000;
    border: none;         /* Reset default border */
    height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```

This is supported in most modern browsers - [support can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Answer (score 10):

Use `frameborder="0"`. Here's a full example:

```
    <iframe src="mypage.htm" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0">Your browser doesnot support iframes<a href="myPageURL.htm"> click here to view the page directly. </a></iframe>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the following attribute:

```
scrolling="no"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this piece of code:

```
  <iframe src="http://example.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

Impossible to say without seeing a live example, but try giving both bodies `margin: 0px`

Comment: @Trufa it could be the margin, but it could also be something else. Best use Firebug's "Layout" view to find out

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to your **iframe** might resolve the issue:

```
frameborder="0"  seamless="seamless"
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @FABBRj Great I could help :D

Comment: FYI, `seamless` is a deprecated attribute and most browsers no longer support it https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_seamless.asp

Answer (score 2):

You could try `frameborder=0`.

Comment: Thanks but that is "inside the iframe" I needed to modify the outside (I didnt know that until @kevingessner answer) thank you!!

Answer (score -3):

Use this code instead of it:

```
    <frameset rows="100%,*">
        <frame src="-------------------------URL-------------------------------">
        <noframes>
            <body>
                Your browser does not support frames. To wiew this page please use supporting browsers.
            </body>
        </noframes>
    </frameset>
```

Comment: No longer supported in HTML5