# html5 iframe for nearly full screen?

Tags: html, iframe, frameset, frameset-iframe

I was looking into using a `frameset` on my otherwise XHTML 1.0 Strict site, but I've noticed that with HTML5 the `frameset` feature is obsolete, and an `iframe` should be used instead.

I need to load a foreign site within my site, with my site only occupying the very top portion of the screen (and it'd be nice if it didn't impede scrolling, either, e.g. looked as if my top portion of my site was actually an iframe within the foreign site).

How do I do this with HTML5 `iframe`?  **Can I set the `height` of the `iframe` to the full-size of the document that's loaded within the `iframe`, and the `width` to full screen width?**  My own site will only be a small one-line menu at the top; the whole screen has to be dedicated to the `iframe` otherwise.

No JavaScript, must be HTML5-only (possibly with some minor CSS, but nothing major, since it has to work in browsers like `lynx` / `links`).

Comment: I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `position` of `fixed` and `absolute`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yqCuT/):

```
<div id="myHeader">My site portion</div>
<div id="myWrapper"><iframe id="myIframe" src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<div style='position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;background-color:red;'>other Site</div>"></iframe></div>


body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#myHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#myWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#myIframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this seems to leave me with three scrolling bars (one vertical, two horizontal), instead of just one; I want only one scrolling bar, probably the main one, and I want my own content to scroll out of view, to make more room for the content referenced in the iframe

Comment: The scrollbars are a matter of tuning margins and overflow. Scrolling out of view can be done by changing `fixed` to `absolute`. Giving the iframe full height will require a little bit of JS though (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Correction: this is actually impossible without control of the child page because of Javascript cross-domain issues.