# How widely supported is the iframe attribute "allowfullscreen"?

Tags: html, iframe, w3c-validation

I can't seem to find any websites detailing the support for the iframe attribute "allowfullscreen". CanIUse.com doesn't seem to have a listing for it, for example.

Does anyone have the support information for Chrome, Safari, IE and Firefox?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe

Comment: @Phorden Nope. Not even close. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't see how that does not help

Comment: @pattyd The questions are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've started discovering some of my own answers:

**FireFox**: Added support in v18 (January 8, 2013) - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/18?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Firefox_18_for_developers#HTML)
**Chrome**: Added support in v27 (May 22, 2013) - [Source](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110374)
**Safari:** Added support in v7 (October 22, 2013) - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
**Internet Explorer:**  Added support in v11
**Microsoft Edge:** Supported

It seems to be difficult to find detailed release notes for the other three, unfortunately.

Comment: IE 9, 10, 11 and Edge support the attribute ("[allowfullscreen property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn312070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" in MS talk) according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There’s a website dedicated to this attribute: http://www.allowfullscreen.com/. It's not very good, however.

While [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn312070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has only a rudimental entry, **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility)** provides a support table in their `iframe` doc:

- FF: 18
- Chrome: 17 (`webkitallowfullscreen`)
- IE: *no support*
- Safari: *prefix support*
- Opera: *supported*

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
CanIUse.com reports [support in all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_iframe_allowfullscreen) now.

Looks like this attribute is part of the HTML 5.1 specification.
This [WC3 implementation report](http://w3c.github.io/test-results/html51/implementation-report.html) claims support in all browsers, so

```
<iframe allowfullscreen>
```

should work, except Microsoft browsers which need the `-ms-` vendor prefix.