# jQuery pop image from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame with images is there any way with jquery make them clickable and show them outside of iframe?

This is what i have:

```
    $(".my-image").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('img').css({
            'width': '600px',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'left': '50%',
            'top': '10px'
        })
    });
```

But image still sits inside of iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not of the CSS tricks i'm aware of helped. Had to get together little jQuery plugin for that:

https://github.com/rinchik/iFramebox

Works like a charm ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you 1) set `allowfullscreen` (and its various vendor prefix variants) on the iframe, and 2) use fixed positioning, you can escape the iframe.

I should mention that browser support is sketchy: [How widely supported is the iframe attribute "allowfullscreen"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113909/is-the-iframe-attribute-allowfullscreen-supported)

Comment: was good idea but didnt work :( i had to do some tricks to get image our of iframe. Got together little jQuery plugin for that: https://github.com/rinchik/iFramebox