# html open new tab with playing sound

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to open a new tab. For example, this is what I have:

```
<a href="pdfs/award_2.pdf" target="_blank" style="font-size:17px">Award</a></span>
```

This code, will open a new tab, and loads my award_2.pdf file. But how can I also do something that it plays a music also when the new tab is opened? And how can I make such that when I close the new tab, the music stops as well?

I also already have the audio tag code:

```
<audio id="audio1_3"><source src="sounds/audio1_3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="sounds/audio1_3.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

But how can I make this plays/stops by opening/closing the pdf file?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new html file in the same folder where is your pdf file located and put this code in that html file.

```
 <audio autoplay>
  <source src="youraudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="youraudio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> 
   <iframe id="viewer" src="yourpdffile.pdf" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" height="500" width="700"></iframe>
```

save the file(change path in the code as necessary).
Point the Anchor to the new html file.

```
<a href="newhtmlfile.html" target="_blank" style="font-size:17px">Award</a></span>
```

Thats it.

Comment: thanks a lot. this is exactly what i needed. worked perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

try setting onfocus and onblur events to your code:

```
ex:

window.onfocus=function(){
    //stop the music
}
window.onblur=function(){
    //play the music
}
```

note: this will not stop the music when you close the new tab, but only when you navigate back to the original tab.

see [onfocus](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) and [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open the new tab with the music "inside"? If so, it's [not recommended](http://www.punkchip.com/autoplay-is-bad-for-all-users/) but, let me try to help you.

You can display the .pdf using an iframe (it's [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice) too).

To play the audio you can use the [audio tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) by HTML5:

```
<audio src="audio.ogg" autoplay loop>
  <p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
```

And then, display the iframe below with the .pdf file.

```
<iframe src="pdf.pdf"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to set the iframe to [full page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe).