# iFrame fullscreen with viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iFrame in fullscreen using tips from: ["Full screen" <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe) and yes, it's working. The problem is that the page the iFrame is referring to is responsive, but the responsivines of this site is not working inside the iFrame.

So I thought adding viewport tag would solve the problem, and yes, it's scaling properly but this makes it impossible to scroll on the page (iPhone).

Is there a way to solve this issue? Maybe some JS could fix this but then I don't know how. The style.css contains CSS-reset.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://something.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
          Your browser doesn't support IFrames
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get the problem. I tried linking to this chart - http://stunni.ng/charts/index.php?call=Chart&type=loadchart&output=html&chart_id=1463 - and it works fine.

Comment: @JasTonAChair Thanks for reply. On computers it works fine as it seems. On my iPhone it's not working that fine anymore and I have tested this on Android phones as well in a nearby shop. I tested your link and it works fine on computers but not in my iPhone. Did you manage to get it to work on your mobile phone with the code above?

Comment: Right, phone, I get it now. I didn't use a phone. I'll chuck it on my server tonight and see how it goes

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height/27853830#27853830