# display Subdomain address on URL bar

Tags: subdomain, hosting, cpanel

I create a sub domain and must add link to redirect. now, when someone click the new link - sub.domain.com the url on the top change to the redirection link like: www.domain.com/folder/folder/index.html.
if i want that when someone click on the sub.domain.com the link in the top still be the same and will not change? Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by pointing the subdomain to a page with a full screen iframe pointing to the target URL

["Full screen" <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe)

Comment: there is only one way? because i want that users can see the URL... but the url needs to be the sum.domain.com

Comment: Ah, I think I got your question wrong, so what you want seems to be that both the base domain and the subdomain URLs are equivalent?

Example:    domain.com/path/page.htm    be the same as    sub.domain.com/path/page.htm    ?