# Iframe saying file not found instead of displaying the website

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to show an entire website inside an html page. But it is looking at my local resources and showing file not found.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;            /* Reset default margin */
}
iframe {
    display: block;       /* iframes are inline by default */
    background: #000;
    border: none;         /* Reset default border */
    height: 100vh;        /* Viewport-relative units */
    width: 100vw;
}
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have changed anything in URL. Please clear your cache and try again. (Like if you didn't used http:// first and now added that )