# Fit content to iframe on mobile browser

Tags: android, html, css, iframe, mobile

I have a page with the following simple markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>embed example</title>
        <style>
        .wrapper {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .container {
            height: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .container iframe {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/238498461&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It looks great on my pc:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLU9b.png

However, when I try loading it in Chrome on my Android phone, the content inside the iframe fails to resize to the iframe dimensions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ4Kn.png

How can I get it to look the same way on my phone as it does on my pc?

Comment: Do you have access to the Iframe?

Comment: Have you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I don't control what's in the what's hosted in that url shown inside the src parameter of the iframe, but I can always embed that on a page manipulate the page it's embedded in.