# fullscreen button mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, fullscreen

I have a embedded game on my website.

I've created a full-screen button in JavaScript and it is working on desktops; but when I press the button on my Galaxy S6, the screen is not in full-screen but somehow it thinks it is cause I can't scroll anymore.

The game is in an iFrame, so I gave it an ID to communicate with the button.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe 
    id="game" 
    style="width:337px;height:600px;border:0;" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    msallowfullscreen="true" 
    mozallowfullscreen="true" 
    webkitallowfullscreen="true" 
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-orientation-lock allow-popups" 
    src="https://games.scirra.net/games/1787/">
</iframe>
<a class="btn color-1" 
   onclick="makeFullscreen('game')">
    Volledig scherm!
</a>
<script>
    function makeFullscreen(id){    
        var el = document.getElementById(id);   
        if  (el.requestFullScreen      ) el.requestFullScreen();    
        else if (el.webkitRequestFullScreen) el.webkitRequestFullScreen();  
        else if (el.mozRequestFullScreen   ) el.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
```

Comment: Tested it on the chrome browser on my mobile. There it seems to work fine. I think it has something to do with the new android internet 4 browser?

Comment: I tested this with chrome on jsfiddle, i'm puzzled, but it didn't work at all. You might want to check this out tho: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14738668/3880255

Comment: That's working but not like I want it to be. I'm trying to get the iframe to cover the whole screen by pressing the button

Comment: What about that? https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/v8j89uf3/

Comment: I really like that setting, but the button is not working again in mobile browsers, in jsfiddle it works great. on my mobile device it is not changing the style="" tag

Comment: That is really strange, thought it might be a issue with actual standard fullscreen, but it must be a issue with your device(-type) in general then. Maybe there is a setting that prevents that or something.

Comment: Just to exclude that option, try this: http://www.solvemix.com/index.php/android-smartphones/721-samsung-galaxy-s6-activate-java-script-on-android-browser

Comment: Javascript is already enabled. really strange. if I put the style settings ( style = "position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" ) directly into the <iframe> tag than it loads in fullscreen. but When you put the code the communicate with a button nothing happens on mobile devices. on dekstops it is working all fine!

Comment: It seems to be an bug in the android browser, downloaded chrome and firefox mobile browsers. There it seems to work properly

Comment: Just as i thought, seemed really strange!