# How to play YouTube embedded video fullscreen from a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

Say, if I have an `iframe` on the page that allows users to play a YouTube video in it, as such:

```
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/--id--"
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to have a link (or a button) below it that would allow to play it full-screen when someone clicks it?

```
<p>Click <a href="???">here</a> to play it full screen.</p>
```

PS. I don't use JQuery or any other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14738668/6121568) answer:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");


document.getElementById("fullScreen").addEventListener("click", function(){

iframe.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;");



});
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oR_e9y-bka0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p id="fullScreen">Click here to play it full screen.</p>
```

Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/2vgsb64a/ because SO framing brocks youtube.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. Although there's a little problem with that method. Once the video is played, there's no way for the user to bring back the page. Thus I was looking for a "YouTube approved" method of doing it. I.e. the same when a user clicks "full screen" button in their player.

Comment: @c00000fd you asked for a way to full screen the video using something outside the iframe : ) . The is no way  back since we are not anymore in the parent page. The only way I think is to communicate with the iframe using its API and post message methods https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference . But to be honest I don't know if it's possible.