# How can I have a wordpress page and a windows server web application under the same domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

I have a web application on C# on a Windows server under some domain. I want to change the look of the home page with WordPress adding a landing page and some news related. I don't have easy access to the Windows server machine. I have quick access just to the FTP. In order to make a change on the server I have to make a request and this takes time. Also I have quick access to the domain configuration.

I want to keep WordPress on another server but I don't know what should I do to keep the same domain on the URL. By example:

`example.com/wordpress` -> go to WordPress server

`example.com/` -> go to Windows server web application

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Search for `.htaccess` and `redirect`. However, I don't know by your post if you have access on the root file system of your web server or not. Probably your C# web application runs on a different port than wordpress, which probably runs on 80 and/or 443.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Can you post this as an answer please?

Comment: @feeela tbh this is more a hint for an answer and not a complete answer since 1. I assume that he can access the web server's file system and 2. I dont remember the correct syntax for a redirecting rule. There are many topics about this issue and I speak by experience: In practice, many of those won't work.

Comment: I don't have direct access to the root file system. Just to the application files. I would like an alternative. I want to keep the wordpress server in another hoisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be  achieved by having something like NginX or HaProxy listening for all requests on HTTP/HTTPS ports and mapping requests to the relevant backend based on the path requested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I will take the easy way using a full screen iframe showing the wordpress page. Is not the cleanest solution but It will do it. I will foillow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe