# how do I show full screen video when called iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

How do I play a YouTube linked video on full screen of my device when called

```
                <iframe id="videoplayer1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen = "true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
                </iframe>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Full screen" <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982422/full-screen-iframe)